# Update query in mysqli failed

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to update columns **password** and **email** from a **table**, here id is the id of selected row.

update query in getting failed

```
require('dbconfig.php');
$id = $_GET['id'];
//echo "id is ",$id;
$sql1 = mysqli_query($con,"select * from login");
if(!$sql1)
{
    echo "Query failed1";
}
else
{
    $sql_num = mysqli_num_rows($sql1); // Returns No. of rows
    echo "Rows are ",$sql_num;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql1))
    {
        //echo "Id in add is ",$id;
        if($row['client_id']==$id)// selects the row whic is equal to the id of the session
        {
            echo $sq1;
            echo "Name : ",$row['username'] . " " . "Password : ",$row['password'] . "<br>";
            if($row['client_id']==$id){
            $sql1_update = mysqli_query($con,"Update login Set password = '".$_POST['$password']."', email = '".$_POST['$email']."'"); // Throwing error Fatal error: Function name must be a string in...
            echo "Successfully Inserted";*/
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also love how `echo "Name : ",$row['username'] . " " . "Password : ",$row['password'] . "<br>";` suggests that the password column is not encrypted

Comment: What do you think the error message refers to?

Comment: I'm new to php..
first I tried  $password=$_POST['password'] and then in update query used $password

Comment: You have comment the first bracket { on your last if but not the second one.

Comment: And you should read up on: 1. SQL injection, 2. password hashing, 3. SQL `WHERE` clauses / `UPDATE` syntax.

Comment: why you are using if($sq1=$row['client_id']==$id), i think it  should be if($row['client_id']==$id)

Comment: @SanjivDhakal The real question is, why is the OP looping over all rows in the database to update one row ;-)

Comment: after if condition i need to store returned value to variable $sq1

Comment: @Asha N. Have provided you with clear explanation about your Error and solution to your code. Have a try and let me know if you face any hindrance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **NOT FOLLOWING** the `basic syntax of the UPDATE` and you have to change the UPDATE code as it has been followed in SQL Community.

**Update Syntax:**

The UPDATE statement is used to update existing records in a table:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

> **Notice the WHERE clause in the UPDATE syntax:** The WHERE clause specifies which record or records that should be updated. If you omit the WHERE clause, all records will be updated!

However, the full syntax for the MySQL UPDATE statement when updating one table is:

```
UPDATE [ LOW_PRIORITY ] [ IGNORE ]
table
SET column1 = expression1,
    column2 = expression2,
    ...
[WHERE conditions]
[ORDER BY expression [ ASC | DESC ]]
[LIMIT number_rows];
```

OR

The syntax for the UPDATE statement when updating one table with data from another table in MySQL is:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = (SELECT expression1
               FROM table2
               WHERE conditions)
[WHERE conditions];
```

OR

The syntax for the MySQL UPDATE statement when updating multiple tables is:

```
UPDATE table1, table2, ... 
SET column1 = expression1,
    column2 = expression2,
    ...
WHERE table1.column = table2.column
AND conditions;
```

## Solution For your Problem

**You Error Code:**

```
$sql1_update = mysqli_query($con,"Update login Set password = '".$_POST['$password']."', email = '".$_POST['$email']."'")
```

**Explanation:** Here you have not provided the `id` in which field ID you have to update the data.

Hence your code should be like this as follows.

**Correct Code:**

> If you need to update with the help of the `$_REQUEST[]` that you make you code should be as follows.

```
<?php
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$sql1_update = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE login SET password = '".$_POST['$password']."', email = '".$_POST['$email']."' WHERE `id`='".$id."'"); 
?>
```

After making all the checks above if still it fails you can make the note below.

> **Note:** Put the echo to the statement and then exit the operation over there. After that you will see the query over to the browser and then copy that query and place in the SQL section and execute the query over there. If you fins all the Operations are correct then you remove the exit and echo and then run the code.

Hope so this explanation might be clear for your understanding purpose.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hi @Naresh Kumar P Thanku fr brief note on update query

BUT, The problem is when I use Where clause to check condition Query fails

Like

$sql1_update = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE login SET password = '".$_POST['password']."', email = '".$_POST['email']."' WHERE `id`='".$id."'");
    if($sql1_update)
    {
     echo "Successfully updated";
    }
    else
    {
     echo "Query failed";
    }

Comment: Have u echoed the Update Query and seen what error do you get. Copy the echoed query and paste it into the SQL Section of the PHPMYADMIN and select GO. If the Error goes correct without any error you can than solve the issue Ensure that you get all the values into the query on update

Comment: Happy to hear it from you ... If my code has helped for achieving your target you can award my answer as the best one by accepting it... Awaiting for your positive response from you ... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Please do understand what the error states, and do some research, but I'll answer you this time.

Replace `$_POST('$password')` with `$_POST['password']`, and `$_POST('$email')` with `$_POST['email']`. `$_POST` **is** **an** **array**; **not** **a** **function**.

Also, you have accidentally (I think) commented out your open curly brace of this `if statement`:

```
if ($sq1 ==1) 
    //  {
```

Lastly, the **update statement** should be:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

> Notice the WHERE clause in the SQL UPDATE statement!
>   The WHERE clause specifies which record or records that should be updated. If you omit the WHERE clause, all records will be updated!

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).

Comment: I think you meant `$_POST['email']`

Comment: mysqli_update query is not executing and previous password value from db are deleted everytime I execute

Comment: @AshaN Updated my answer again.

Comment: @Rax Weber Thank You for response

Comment: how to update from php form i.e I've php page from where I wil be giving new values for fields email nd pwd

Comment: I'm using php 5.6.14, when i give where clause query fails so I'm using if condition like

$sq = mysqli_query($con,"Select * from login");
 if(!$sq){
  echo "Query failed";
  }
  else
  {
   $sq_num = mysqli_num_rows($sq);
   echo "num rows ",$sq_num;
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sq)){
    if($_SESSION['username']==$row['username']){
                                    echo "Something";
                                    }
                              }}}

Answer (score 0):

Is any part of your file deprecated? If so that will throw an error every time. Deprecated code and updated code will not talk to each other. I figured that out the hard way.

Comment: deprecated issues are resolved....

I've login page after which users should be able to edit their profile nd update it to database PROBLEM is with UPDATE query in SET column_name = value? what shuld be given if many users want to update